# MySQL query all outcome from a table where the field's values all exist in another table

Tags: mysql, sql, select

For example, merchant(m_id), bill(b_id, m_id, payer_name) How can I get all payer who buy from every merchant?  I used `group by` and compare the count, but the bill can occur times by same payer and same merchant. I think I need some function like`where m_id in all (select m_id from merchant)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple ways of doing this.  Here's one using a subquery:

```
select payer_name
from bill 
group by payer_name
having count(distinct m_id) = (select count(*) from merchant)
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6e6412/1)